# how do I create a laravel factory that references another models mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, factories

I am trying to create a factory for a "posts" model

I need the community_id field filled with random selections from the communities table in the id column.
I also need to fill the user_id field with random selections from the communities table in the id column.

Can you please help me with how to code this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get random ids from a table by doing something like `DB::table('talbename')->inRandomOrder()->take(X)->pluck('id')` (where X is the number of entries you want) you can replace `DB::table` with your model name as well.

Comment: If you Communities table has an eloquent model, select the ids you need, query for some data. Result is a kind of collection, so its easy to get a random value from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with an answer and it is the following:

```
    public function definition()
    {
        $userIDs = DB::table('users')->pluck('id');
        return [
            'user_id' => $faker->randomElement($userIDs),
            'name' => fake()->sentence(),
            'description' => fake()->sentence(),
        ];
    }
```

Using `DB::table('users')->pluck('id')` allows us to use the DB facade provided by Laravel to reference the `users` table and pluck the `id` column.

We are then saving this array of results in a `$userIds` variable which we then use in the `return` inside the `definition()` method, where in the `'user_id'` key value pair we call `$faker->randomElement($userIds)` which is a helper function that will select a random item from an array of values passed to it, which in this case we have passed an array of the user ids.

I hope this solution helps those who might need assistance in the future with this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).